# Convert Java object to a Ballerina JSON value

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake, ballerina-java-interop

Is it possible to convert Java objects into Ballerina objects and/or JSON types? I want to use the POI Java package to read XLSX and make it available in Ballerina land as a `record[]` or `json[]` or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this using Java interoperability and the bindgen tool to generate Ballerina objects corresponding to Java objects. Check out the following resources for more information:

- [Call Java Code from Ballerina](https://ballerina.io/learn/call-java-code-from-ballerina)
- [Java Interoperability Guide](https://ballerina.io/learn/java-interoperability-guide/java-interoperability)

However, note that there is no direct way to convert Java objects to Ballerina records or JSON types. Here are a couple of options:

1. If you have a string representation in JSON format, you can use the [`fromJsonStringWithType`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/0.0.0/functions#fromJsonStringWithType) function to convert it to an array of JSON or records.

   ```php
   import ballerina/jballerina.java;

   type Employee record {|
       int id;
       string name;
       json...;
   |};

   // `jsonJavaStr` is the Java String that is in JSON format.
   function convertToEmployees(handle jsonJavaStr) returns Employee[]|error {
       string? jsonBalStr = java:toString(jsonJavaStr);

       if jsonBalStr is () {
           return error("expected non-empty string");
       }

       return jsonBalStr.fromJsonStringWithType();
   }
   ```
2. You could create the Java representation of `json[]` in an external function you implement (actual conversion would happen in Java). For example, creating a `io.ballerina.runtime.api.values.BArray` value using [`io.ballerina.runtime.api.creators.ValueCreator#createArrayValue`](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/v2201.3.2/bvm/ballerina-runtime/src/main/java/io/ballerina/runtime/api/creators/ValueCreator.java#L202).

   ```php
   // `javaObj` is the reference to the Java object.
   function constructJsonArray(handle javaObj) returns json[] = external;
   ```

   This approach involves more work since you'll have to create a new array type and recursively parse/map the values too.